# Variance of a dice roll

Tags: probability

I am currently working on a problem and am unsure if I approached it correctly. Here it is:

> The random variable $X$ is defined to be the number of ones obtained in 
>   $n$ tosses of a fair, six-sided die. Determine the variance of $X$.

Here is what I did:

Variance = $x*\sigma^2(x) = n*p(1-p)$

$n*(1/6)*(1-(1/6)) = .139n$

Does this look as if I used the right equation?

Answer (score 1):

Until you wrote 1.39 for $\frac{1}{6} \frac{5}{6}$, your equation was right.  The answer is $\sigma^2 = \frac{5n}{36}$

Comment: Okay I miswrote that after checking my work as it should have been .139n which is 5/36.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), the equation that you have used is the variance of this distribution so kudos to you.

Comment: Oh interesting. Does this still work correctly?